How to fix the indentation problem for Javascript/Typescript on Neovim?
Problem Description
It's been a week since I started taking Neovim (lazyvim). Neovim has been used by me exclusively for Python and MERN Stack development. The indentation in Python is operating flawlessly. But at this point, indentation is completely broken. At first, it was functioning normally with only a few minor problems.
Note: I am using WSL Ubuntu 24.04. Neovim version is 0.9.5.
Before the problem was like,
const element = (
  <div>
  | <h1>Hello!</h1>
  | <h2>Good to see you here.</h2>
  </div>
);

The pointer used to be at the start of the line of indents that is being used now. Just pressed the tab key to get to the right line with a space between the words.
To fix this, I tried to get some approved plugins for lazyvim from the website for lazyvim. But after I downloaded and tried some plugins, I saw that the gap that was happening before was no longer happening. Instead, the indentation is no longer happening at all.
Current Situation
const func = () => {
    // For now, till this level indentation is working fine. But as soon as I introduce a new indentation level, the indentation breaks. 
}

I have noticed that in .js and .ts file, the indentation is working for only one indentation level.
Only Python code is working perfectly.
Note
I'm new to neovim. So, could you please help me solve this problem? I can give you my configuration codes to help you figure out what's wrong.
lua/config/lazy.lua
local lazypath = vim.fn.stdpath("data") .. "/lazy/lazy.nvim"
if not (vim.uv or vim.loop).fs_stat(lazypath) then
  local lazyrepo = "https://github.com/folke/lazy.nvim.git"
  local out = vim.fn.system({ "git", "clone", "--filter=blob:none", "--branch=stable", lazyrepo, lazypath })
  if vim.v.shell_error ~= 0 then
    vim.api.nvim_echo({
      { "Failed to clone lazy.nvim:\n", "ErrorMsg" },
      { out, "WarningMsg" },
      { "\nPress any key to exit..." },
    }, true, {})
    vim.fn.getchar()
    os.exit(1)
  end
end
vim.opt.rtp:prepend(lazypath)

require("lazy").setup({
  spec = {
    -- add L
    { "LazyVim/LazyVim", import = "lazyvim.plugins" },
    -- import/override with your plugins
    { import = "lazyvim.plugins.extras.lang.typescript" },
    { import = "lazyvim.plugins.extras.lang.python" },
    { import = "lazyvim.plugins.extras.lang.json" },
    { import = "lazyvim.plugins.extras.ui.mini-indentscope" },
    { import = "lazyvim.plugins.extras.ui.mini-animate" },
    { import = "plugins" },
  },
  defaults = {
    -- By default, only LazyVim plugins will be lazy-loaded. Your custom plugins will load during startup.
    -- If you know what you're doing, you can set this to `true` to have all your custom plugins lazy-loaded by default.
    lazy = false,
    -- It's recommended to leave version=false for now, since a lot the plugin that support versioning,
    -- have outdated releases, which may break your Neovim install.
    version = false, -- always use the latest git commit
    -- version = "*", -- try installing the latest stable version for plugins that support semver
  },
  install = { colorscheme = { "tokyonight", "habamax" } },
  checker = {
    enabled = true, -- check for plugin updates periodically
    notify = false, -- notify on update
  }, -- automatically check for plugin updates
  performance = {
    rtp = {
      -- disable some rtp plugins
      disabled_plugins = {
        "gzip",
        -- "matchit",
        -- "matchparen",
        -- "netrwPlugin",
        "tarPlugin",
        "tohtml",
        "tutor",
        "zipPlugin",
      },
    },
  },
})

lua/config/options.lua
vim.g.mapleader = " "

vim.scriptencoding = "utf-8"
vim.opt.encoding = "utf-8"
vim.opt.fileencoding = "utf-8"

vim.opt.number = true

vim.opt.title = true
vim.opt.autoindent = true
vim.opt.smartindent = true
vim.opt.hlsearch = true
vim.opt.backup = false
vim.opt.showcmd = true
vim.opt.cmdheight = 0
vim.opt.laststatus = 0
vim.opt.expandtab = true
vim.opt.scrolloff = 10
vim.opt.inccommand = "split"
vim.opt.ignorecase = true
vim.opt.smarttab = true
vim.opt.breakindent = true
vim.opt.shiftwidth = 2
vim.opt.tabstop = 2
vim.opt.wrap = false
vim.opt.backspace = { "start", "eol", "indent" }
vim.opt.path:append({ "**" })
vim.opt.wildignore:append({ "*/node_modules/*" })
vim.opt.splitbelow = true
vim.opt.splitright = true
vim.opt.splitkeep = "cursor"

-- Add asterisks in block comments
vim.opt.formatoptions:append({ "r" })

lua/plugins/example.lua
-- since this is just an example spec, don't actually load anything here and return an empty spec
-- stylua: ignore
if true then return {} end

-- every spec file under the "plugins" directory will be loaded automatically by lazy.nvim
--
-- In your plugin files, you can:
-- * add extra plugins
-- * disable/enabled LazyVim plugins
-- * override the configuration of LazyVim plugins
return {
  -- add gruvbox
  { "ellisonleao/gruvbox.nvim" },

  -- Configure LazyVim to load gruvbox
  {
    "LazyVim/LazyVim",
    opts = {
      colorscheme = "gruvbox",
    },
  },

  -- change trouble config
  {
    "folke/trouble.nvim",
    -- opts will be merged with the parent spec
    opts = { use_diagnostic_signs = true },
  },

  -- disable trouble
  { "folke/trouble.nvim", enabled = false },

  -- override nvim-cmp and add cmp-emoji
  {
    "hrsh7th/nvim-cmp",
    dependencies = { "hrsh7th/cmp-emoji" },
    ---@param opts cmp.ConfigSchema
    opts = function(_, opts)
      table.insert(opts.sources, { name = "emoji" })
    end,
  },

  -- change some telescope options and a keymap to browse plugin files
  {
    "nvim-telescope/telescope.nvim",
    keys = {
      -- add a keymap to browse plugin files
      -- stylua: ignore
      {
        "<leader>fp",
        function() require("telescope.builtin").find_files({ cwd = require("lazy.core.config").options.root }) end,
        desc = "Find Plugin File",
      },
    },
    -- change some options
    opts = {
      defaults = {
        layout_strategy = "horizontal",
        layout_config = { prompt_position = "top" },
        sorting_strategy = "ascending",
        winblend = 0,
      },
    },
  },

  -- add pyright to lspconfig
  {
    "neovim/nvim-lspconfig",
    ---@class PluginLspOpts
    opts = {
      ---@type lspconfig.options
      servers = {
        -- pyright will be automatically installed with mason and loaded with lspconfig
        pyright = {},
      },
    },
  },

  -- add tsserver and setup with typescript.nvim instead of lspconfig
  {
    "neovim/nvim-lspconfig",
    dependencies = {
      "jose-elias-alvarez/typescript.nvim",
      init = function()
        require("lazyvim.util").lsp.on_attach(function(_, buffer)
          -- stylua: ignore
          vim.keymap.set( "n", "<leader>co", "TypescriptOrganizeImports", { buffer = buffer, desc = "Organize Imports" })
          vim.keymap.set("n", "<leader>cR", "TypescriptRenameFile", { desc = "Rename File", buffer = buffer })
        end)
      end,
    },
    ---@class PluginLspOpts
    opts = {
      ---@type lspconfig.options
      servers = {
        -- tsserver will be automatically installed with mason and loaded with lspconfig
        tsserver = {},
      },
      -- you can do any additional lsp server setup here
      -- return true if you don't want this server to be setup with lspconfig
      ---@type table<string, fun(server:string, opts:_.lspconfig.options):boolean?>
      setup = {
        -- example to setup with typescript.nvim
        tsserver = function(_, opts)
          require("typescript").setup({ server = opts })
          return true
        end,
        -- Specify * to use this function as a fallback for any server
        -- ["*"] = function(server, opts) end,
      },
    },
  },

  -- for typescript, LazyVim also includes extra specs to properly setup lspconfig,
  -- treesitter, mason and typescript.nvim. So instead of the above, you can use:
  { import = "lazyvim.plugins.extras.lang.typescript" },

  -- add more treesitter parsers
  {
    "nvim-treesitter/nvim-treesitter",
    opts = {
      ensure_installed = {
        "bash",
        "html",
        "javascript",
        "json",
        "lua",
        "markdown",
        "markdown_inline",
        "python",
        "query",
        "regex",
        "tsx",
        "typescript",
        "vim",
        "yaml",
      },
    },
  },

  -- since `vim.tbl_deep_extend`, can only merge tables and not lists, the code above
  -- would overwrite `ensure_installed` with the new value.
  -- If you'd rather extend the default config, use the code below instead:
  {
    "nvim-treesitter/nvim-treesitter",
    opts = function(_, opts)
      -- add tsx and treesitter
      vim.list_extend(opts.ensure_installed, {
        "tsx",
        "typescript",
      })
    end,
  },

  -- the opts function can also be used to change the default opts:
  {
    "nvim-lualine/lualine.nvim",
    event = "VeryLazy",
    opts = function(_, opts)
      table.insert(opts.sections.lualine_x, {
        function()
          return ""
        end,
      })
    end,
  },

  -- or you can return new options to override all the defaults
  {
    "nvim-lualine/lualine.nvim",
    event = "VeryLazy",
    opts = function()
      return {
        --[[add your custom lualine config here]]
      }
    end,
  },

  -- use mini.starter instead of alpha
  { import = "lazyvim.plugins.extras.ui.mini-starter" },

  -- add jsonls and schemastore packages, and setup treesitter for json, json5 and jsonc
  { import = "lazyvim.plugins.extras.lang.json" },

  -- add any tools you want to have installed below
  {
    "williamboman/mason.nvim",
    opts = {
      ensure_installed = {
        "stylua",
        "shellcheck",
        "shfmt",
        "flake8",
      },
    },
  },
}

Nothing I read or watched on YouTube, Stack Overflow, Github, or Reddit helped me resolve this problem.
